# Only first vertex of data used in shader OpenGL

Tags: voxels, vbo, perlin-noise, data, water

I'm making a voxel game like Minecraft which was working fine until I added water. Then I realized that whatever the texture was for the first visible block was applied to the rest of the blocks in the chunk. I am drawing a total of 36 vertices per cube and it seems that although the instanced array for the cube positions is working, only the first 36 texture coordinates are being used.

[image]

[image]

I raised all visible ocean. Locks in the second picture which is how I determined the actual coastline.

creating the buffers

glGenVertexArrays(1,&chunk->chunkVAO);
    //glGenBuffers(1,&chunk->chunkEBO);
    glGenBuffers(1,&chunk->cubeVBO);
    glGenBuffers(1,&chunk->posOffsetVBO);
    glGenBuffers(1,&chunk->texCoordVBO);

```
glBindVertexArray(chunk->chunkVAO);



glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,chunk->cubeVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(cubeVertices),cubeVertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,chunk->texCoordVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(glm::vec2)*36*65536,NULL,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);


glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,2*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);



glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,chunk->posOffsetVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(glm::vec3)*65536,NULL,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribDivisor(2,1);
```

filling the texture and position VBO after occlusion culling

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,chunk->texCoordVBO);

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,sizeof(texCoords),&texCoords[0]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,chunk->posOffsetVBO);

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,sizeof(positions),&positions[0]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
```

rendering

```
glBindVertexArray(temp->chunkVAO);


glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES,0,36,temp->visibleBlocks);
```

How come only one of the blocks worth of texture coordinates is  being  used?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to help and find the issue.

Comment: If you want to take pictures of your screen, use print screen

Comment: Show us the code, where you render stuff

Comment: @Bálint like that?

Comment: Just having a quick look without diving too much into it, but your 3rd GL call from the first snippet seems suspicious. You are calling bufferData with a sizeof on cubeVertices, which is likely a pointer of some sort. I'd assume you instead would mean to do something like sizeof(CubeVertex) * amount of vertices.

Comment: cubevertices is a global array of floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem. I stored all of the textures on a texture atlas and referred to them by including an integer in the instance data. The problem was that I used `glVertexAttribPointer` with the parameter that says the data is normalized. When using integers as vertex attributes you use `glVerteAttribIPointer` (extra I). Then the coastline looked fine.